# Approximation to the flow of the sum of two vector fields.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $X,Y$ smooth vector fields on $M$ with corresponding flows $\Phi^{X}, \Phi^{Y}$. Show that the flow of $X+Y$ is given by,

$$\Phi^{X+Y}_t=\lim_{n \to \infty}\underbrace{\Phi^{X}_{t/n}\circ \Phi^{Y}_{t/n}\circ \cdots  \circ \Phi^{X}_{t/n}\circ \Phi^{Y}_{t/n}}_{n \text{ times}} $$

How should I attack this problem? I cannot find any intuitive idea of why the flow can be approximated by that limit.